\SubMatrix in nicematrix causes the superscript to be colored

As you see in the image, the superscript is colored, but is expected to be of normal color
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[right-margin=1em]
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & a & b \\
        1 & c & d
        \CodeAfter
        \SubMatrix{\lbrack}{2-2}{3-3}{\rbrack}[delimiters/color=gray]^{T}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


you could report it to the author, but simply using ^{\mathcolor{black}{T}} to force the color to restore should also work

You are right. That's a bug in nicematrix and I will correct it.

I have uploaded on CTAN a new version of nicematrix (6.28b of 2024/06/29) which solves that bug.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[right-margin=1em]
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & a & b \\
        1 & c & d
        \CodeAfter
        \SubMatrix{\lbrack}{2-2}{3-3}{\rbrack}[delimiters/color=gray]^{T}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}



Thankss, but downloading and compiling nicematrix-code.dtx produces 6.28a

You should wait a few days till an update of your TeX distribution (TeXLive of MiKTeX) provides the new version of nicematrix. You can also retrieve the version 6.28b of the file nicematrix.sty from the GitHub depot of nicematrix:  https://github.com/fpantigny/nicematrix/releases/tag/v6.28b
